# How can I modify time in Robolectric in order to fire an alarm

Tags: android, time, alarm, robolectric, system-clock

I'm trying to test a method with Robolectric (first contact with Robolectric).
I would like to set the system clock forward in order to fire an alarm, which was previously set with:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, alarmDelay, pendingIntent);
```

I tried to use SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(time + alarmDelay) but it doesn't fire anything.
Should I create a MockedSystemClock, but I don't know which method to use.
Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [`ShadowAlarmManager`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAlarmManager.html) see [Creating a mock AlarmManager for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841499/94363)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Shadow alarm manager doesn't fire alarms either, not that I can see.